# Android: ignore lint check for a specific directory

Tags: android, lint

I'm wondering if I have a project with the following resources structure:

```
src/main/resources/module1

src/main/resources/module2
```

Where each module has its resources directory with values, drawables, etc ..

Now I want to ignore the **IconMissingDensityFolder** check for the resources in **module1** directory **only**.

What does the lint configuration for that look like?

Comment: I wonder why you have such strange project structure. Are modules build variants?

Comment: It just happened, they are not build variats :)

Comment: I wonder how you build process looks to select one of directories while building app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should look like:

```
<lint>
  <issue id="IconMissingDensityFolder">
    <ignore path="**/src/main/resources/module1" />
  </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and update you with the results